# filling one table when something entered to another table

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2005

When i enter omething to table A is it possible somehow that some values will be calculated from the values in table A and the will be a new entry in table B relating those values?

and all of this done in the database and not from the client that updating the database .

I work with MSSQL and MySql , can you give me directions how i can do those things in those databases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trigger for it.

For Mysql,

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

I am not sure about MSSql since i work with Mysql, but you can check,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you will probably be needing a trigger. This may help. see way down for an example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test2 SET a2 = NEW.a1;
    DELETE FROM test3 WHERE a3 = NEW.a1;
    UPDATE test4 SET b4 = b4 + 1 WHERE a4 = NEW.a1;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stored Procedures and fire before insert

Sanil

Answer (score 0):

Create a view instead of table B.